# Can't access The Hangar chat room of aviation.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

I'm on aviation.stackexchange.com where I had a 4000 rep. However, when I go to The Hangar chat, I can't post because it says I need a rep of at least 20. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you have a different chat user for some reason. Your actual [chat user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/105326/terry) was last seen 212 days ago. When you are in the chat lobby, what name do you see on the top bar and where does it link to?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're logged in. The authentication system is a tad complex here, so you might not be doing anything wrong yourself for chat to not recognize you as logged in right away.

You can log out on Aviation and log back in to be sure, or hit up [this link](https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fusers%2fchat-login) and log in the same way you usually do. You should get redirected back to chat at that point and it will recognize you as a site user.

If that doesn't do it, Shadow Wizard's advice in the comments is on point - the next step is to make sure you didn't end up with a different chat profile.

If this doesn't help, [give us a shout](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/contact) and we'll dig further.